# jq - create new object based on existing objects

Tags: json, join, merge, jq, concatenation

This is my very first post, so please forgive me if it is not perfect.

I have json like below. It consists of two parts. The first part contains information about user (id, fullname and email) and the second part contains informations to which team user belongs. (id, team, role)
What I want to get an object which contains: id, fullName, emaila, team and role. I can do it but only when user belongs to one team. If user belongs to more than one team - I can't handle it.

Below my json:

```
[
  {
    "id": "user1",
    "fullName": "User One",
    "email": "user.one@my.mail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "user2",
    "fullName": "User Two",
    "email": "user.two@my.mail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "user1",
    "team": "Team_A",
    "role": "TEAM_MEMBER"
  },
  {
    "id": "user1",
    "team": "Team_B",
    "role": "TEAM_ADMIN"
  },
  {
    "id": "user2",
    "team": "Team_B",
    "role": "TEAM_ADMIN"
  }
]
```

When I use: `group_by(.id)[] | add`
I get:

```
{
  "id": "user1",
  "fullName": "User One",
  "email": "user.one@my.mail.com",
  "team": "Team_B",
  "role": "TEAM_ADMIN"
},
{
  "id": "user2",
  "fullName": "User Two",
  "email": "user.two@my.mail.com",
  "team": "Team_B",
  "role": "TEAM_ADMIN"
}
```

and it is almost what I want to achieve. My goal is:

```
{
  "id": "user1",
  "fullName": "User One",
  "email": "user.one@my.mail.com",
  "team": "Team_A,
  "role": "TEAM_MEMBER"
},
{
  "id": "user1",
  "fullName": "User One",
  "email": "user.one@my.mail.com",
  "team": "Team_B",
  "role": "TEAM_ADMIN"
},
{
  "id": "user2",
  "fullName": "User Two",
  "email": "user.two@my.mail.com",
  "team": "Team_B",
  "role": "TEAM_ADMIN"
}
```

I tried `reduce` also, but with no success.
I have made many attempts, but none of them gave the desired effect.

How is it possible using `jq`?

Thanks in advance,

krzyhon

Comment: The expected output that you show is not valid JSON.  Please clarify.  Do you want a JSON array of the objects with "id" keys? A stream thereof?  Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a collection of bits of information about users. You can't just flatten them down by merging everything that has the same `id`, they need to be separate.

You have "user info" (full name and email) and "team info". You need to group by the id, then by the type, then distribute the "user info".

Here's one approach you could take.

```sh
# partition the data by "user/team type"
reduce .[] as $i ({}; if "fullName" | in($i) then .user += [$i] else .team += [$i] end)

  # create a lookup of "user" data
  | (.user | INDEX(.id)) as $user

  # group the "team" objects by team
  | .team | group_by(.team)

  # merge corresponding "user info" with all team objects
  | map(map(. + $user[.id]))
```

```json
[
  [
    {
      "id": "user1",
      "team": "Team_A",
      "role": "TEAM_MEMBER",
      "fullName": "User One",
      "email": "user.one@my.mail.com"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "user1",
      "team": "Team_B",
      "role": "TEAM_ADMIN",
      "fullName": "User One",
      "email": "user.one@my.mail.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "user2",
      "team": "Team_B",
      "role": "TEAM_ADMIN",
      "fullName": "User Two",
      "email": "user.two@my.mail.com"
    }
  ]
]
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/Ogypt_HqMc)

---

Here's another more concise solution, assuming there will only be one "user info" per id.

```sh
# group by id
group_by(.id) | map(
    # for each group, partition by "type"
    group_by(.fullName)

      # create combinations of all the info and team objects and merge them
      | combinations | add
)
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/0A4VFQmgDs)

Comment: Thanks you @Jeff! You solved my problem!
Now I need to analyse how you did it.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a variant of @JeffMercado's approach based on `combinations`, but only uses `group_by` once (which means that for large datasets, it should be more efficient, since `group_by` is a relatively expensive operation).

The proposed solution here produces an array of the JSON objects you indicate you want, but if you want a stream of the JSON objects, simply omit the outer square brackets.

```
[group_by(.id)[]
 | [map(select(has("team")|not)), map(select(has("team")))]
 | combinations
 | add]
```

#### More efficiently ...

To avoid using `group_by` or `select` at all, we could use the following generic variant of `group_by`:

```
def aggregate_by(s; f):
  reduce s as $x (null; .[$x|f] += [$x]);
```

The solution can now be written as follows:

```
[ aggregate_by(.[]; .id)[]
  | aggregate_by(.[]; .team == null | tostring)
  | [.[]]
  | combinations
  | add ]
```

Comment: Thank you @peak for your response. Since I'm fairly new to jq, could you please point me where I should define aggregate_by ().

Comment: The simplest would be to put all the relevanr code (in the order shown) in a file, and invoke jq with the -f option.